# Naming Practice for domain object named class

Tags: c#, standards

I'm using a ORM and ran across a database table named Class. I've been naming the domain objects the same as their table name. So is Class a valid name for this object? I know it will compile but it doesn't seem like a good practice.

The table is refering to a versioned C# class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not good practice, and personally I would not do it, it compiles because in c# class != Class (its case sensitive)

class and all variations of class should be considered reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

It'll compile, but personally I'd choose a different name to avoid any potential issues or confusion.  Assuming you are talking about classes in the domain of education, maybe "Course" would be a good substitute?

Comment: What would be a different name without losing the integrity of the naming schema itself?

Comment: Its actually refering to a C# class.

Comment: Or ClassType if it's a lookup.

Comment: ClassType would seem to imply the type of class? rather than which class.

Comment: @Will - a database table of C# classes?  It hurts my head to think about such meta-programming :)

Comment: Just a index and version of a class. Its for auditing what class acutally built the data that went into the database. So if at a later date we improve the class we can rebuild the information with the new version of the class.